Present continuous to emphasize
Present continuous- used for things that happen now, around now or for temporal events
Present simple- used for repeatable events, routines.
Can I use present continuous even if something happenes for a long time regularly to emphasize lenght? I will show an example.
Every year it is taking them hours to get here"

Welcome to ELL. If you search previous questions here, you’ll find lots of them to do with continuous verbs. And searching before asking is one of the practices requested here. As it turns out, no, your example sentence is not idiomatic. The thought would be expressed instead by Every year it takes them hours to get here.

Your examples need context. As per usual, it's taking them ages to get here. See this example on the Internet: "This batch brings the total number of v18.0 stable releases so far to 23! As per usual, it's taking longer than I would like, but they are coming together."
